# After unzipping on z/OS USS within bash, what is the command to convert an sh script to the right code page?

Tags: bash, jar, character-encoding, zip, zos

My problem is the charset of the files that get unzip within bash are not UTF8. Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Copy a zip file in binary to USS (ftp - bin - put myfile2unzip.zip)
2. Use the jar command to unzip: jar -xvf myfile2unzip.zip
3. cat myscript.sh

Output:

> {Za???a????{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{@???@....

What I have tried:

```
iconv -f UTF8 -t IBM1047 myscript.sh > myscript.uss
```

That did not work, the output file has the wrong charset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar command in bash was unzipping the files in charset: ISO8859-1
The jar command in sh unzips the files into UTF8.

So the right command in bash is:
iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF8 myscript.sh > myscript.uss

Comment: I‘m not sure I understand what you want to achive. In the first post you translate to an EBCDIC coded page (IBM 1047). In this post you translate from ISO8859-1 to UTF8 which both are more related to ASCII than EBCDIC. Why do you think „jar“ works differently when run in a bash shell versus a sh shell? AFAIK, jar does extract 1:1, i.e. no translation at all. You‘re doing different „iconv“s.

Comment: @phunsoft We started working on USS within sh. When you unzip within /bin/sh the files get converted into one charset (IBM1047). So we thought it should be the same if we perform the same command within bash. However, in USS bash behaves a bit differently as it extracts the files into charset  ISO8859-1. Since we have a requirement to consistently work within bash, we needed to understand what is the right way to unzip files was so that the outcome can be either usable or so that we can provide a command to make them usable. Hence the need to know the charset.